# Determining W3SCV name on AZURE

Tags: iis, azure

I'm sure Azure used to give website nice predictable names starting like "W3SVC1"...

However, currently I'm seeing names in Azure like "W3SVC1273337584" - which doesn't feel quite as predictable. However, searching the web, this doesn't feel like it's a random number as I've seen quite a few other posts using exactly the same name.

Is there any way to determine the name from e.g. the project file? Is there any way to change the number?

I've looked at blog posts around [`ServerManager`](http://www.wadewegner.com/2011/01/programmatically-changing-the-apppool-identity-in-a-windows-azure-web-role/?replytocom=2407) and I'm guessing that somewhere in there is a setting, but I'm wondering if there is any way in the cloud role setup?

Thanks

Stuart

Comment: to what "name" are you referring?  Are you talking about "[name].cloudapp.net"?

Comment: No - I'm talking about the name given to the website within IIS - e.g. the name used for the logging directory

Answer (score 0):

This should be in the environment variables if I'm not mistaken. You can easily read those in your application.